# Firefox: Exiting due to channel error

Tags: 18.04, firefox

I am new to Ubuntu, and I am having problems running Firefox 77 on Ubuntu 18.04. This is the error that shows up:

```
Exiting due to channel error.

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x200055,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateEffects) Channel error: cannot send/recv


(firefox:724): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 15:44:00.357: Unable to get session bus: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=a1179a4949cc463f9b173074c5d11ce1 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x200098,name=PBrowser::Msg_SetDocShellIsActive) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380077,name=PContent::Msg_LoadURI) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380050,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380035,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Parent 724, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-_bVJH1/firefox-77.0~b9+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380035,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Parent 724, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-_bVJH1/firefox-77.0~b9+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380035,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Parent 724, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-_bVJH1/firefox-77.0~b9+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380035,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Parent 724, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-_bVJH1/firefox-77.0~b9+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x380035,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Parent 724, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-_bVJH1/firefox-77.0~b9+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc, line 19
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Comment: According to this resource FF v77 is not yet due for release... https://libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/ Have you installed the beta version?

Comment: Yes you were right, I downgraded to FF v59 and it is working now. Thank you!
I followed the instructions from this website to downgrade FF if anyone is having the same problem: https://vitux.com/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I'll precis that as an answer to help anyone with a similar problem in the meantime. If you would care to accept that as the answer, it will help in that regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/) resource, FireFox version 77 is not yet due for release until early June 2020 and so the version installed in in beta.

The solution was to downgrade to a supported version (the OP downgraded to v59) using [this](https://vitux.com/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/) resource and that solved the problem

Comment: I'm seeing these issues for Firefox 87 on Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL, I'm not sure this is the right answer, though downgrading did obviously work for the OP.